# How to programmatically update the allowed values of a list field?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I have created a select list for a Profile2 account in Drupal 7. In the allowed values list, I have added some values. Now what I would like to do is programmatically update the values in that list (add, delete or update). I don't want to use form_alter as I want these updates committed to the database. My problem is I can't seem to find where these values are stored in the database or how to pull those values from Profile2, update them and then save them.

I have Googled high and low on this particular issue and can't find an answer on how to do this. I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something along the lines of...

```
// Get the field info
$info = field_info_field('field_some_field');

// Get a reference to the values
$values = &$info['settings']['allowed_values'];

// Manipulate the values in some way, e.g.
$values['new_value'] = 'New Value';

// Save the field
field_update_field($info);
```

Comment: where I need to add this  piece of code?

Comment: @shivam You need to add this code to a custom module that you create.

Comment: Put this in a hook_update_N to run just one time.

Comment: Also this won't change old allowed values if the field is already in use.

Answer (score 3):

You'd better use the `allowed_values_function` with a callback:

```
'settings' => array(
  'allowed_values' => array(),
  'allowed_values_function' => '_my_feature_module_options_list',
),
```

See [Creating dynamic allowed values options for an entity field](http://codekarate.com/blog/creating-dynamic-allowed-values-options-entity-field).

Comment: A more complete answer would be helpful.  The code you're referencing is good, and works similar to the accepted answer, but was created for use with the Features module.